# True value of $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{(1-2\sin^2 x)\sqrt{1-4\sin^2 x}}$

Tags: integration, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

During the generation of test values I stumbled over this question

> What is the true value of the complete elliptic integral of the 3rd kind
>   $$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{(1-2\sin^2 x)\sqrt{1-4\sin^2 x}}?$$

This is a special case of the $\Pi$ integral (see e.g. https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2.E7) and the Cauchy principal value has to be taken.

Here are my experiments with some well-known resources:

With Wolfram/Mathematica style elliptic integrals (using parameters) the value should be
$$I=\Pi(2|4)=\mathtt{EllipticPi}[2,4] \approx -0.36396057469 - 0.53912891187i$$

With Maple style integrals (using modulus) it should be
$$I=\Pi(2,2)=\mathtt{EllipticPi}(2,2) \approx 1.20683575210 - 0.53912891187 i$$
(Note  that the imaginary parts are the same).

In order to resolve the different results, I asked Wolfram Alpha to evaluate the integral using

`int(1/((1-2*sin(x)^2)*sqrt(1-4*sin(x)^2)), x=0..Pi/2) with 30 digits`

as input and got the very disturbing **different (!?)** results

```
Computation result:    1.05574680871 - 3.53800841627 i 
Decimal approximation: 1.11534422571 + 1.91703566486 i
```

Pari/GP 2.9.4 gives another numerical integration result

```
? intnum(x=0,Pi/2,1/((1-2*sin(x)^2)*sqrt(1-4*sin(x)^2)))
%1 = 1.046038054724273208736077496 + 4.797148009326248296 E27*I
```

---

**Edit (May 2018):** I did not expect an answer after two month, therefore I update
the question. Since I am interested in the real part only, I meanwhile use the following formulas:

For $|k|>1, \nu \ne k^2$ the following formula (derived from http://functions.wolfram.com/08.06.04.0029.01 with $x=\pi/2$):
$$
\Re \Pi(\nu,k) = \frac{1}{k}\; \Pi\left(\frac{\nu}{k^2} , \frac{1}{k}\right)
- \Re \left(\frac{\pi}{2} \; \sqrt{\frac{\nu}{(\nu - 1)(k^2 - \nu)}}\;\;\right)
$$
(the second term is zero for $k^2 < \nu$), 
and for $\nu=k^2 > 1$ the result is (c.f. http://functions.wolfram.com/08.03.03.0003.01):
$$
\Pi(k^2,k)\ = \frac{E(k)}{1-k^2}\;\cdot
$$

Comment: I think your integral does not converge.

Comment: @dr-sonnhard-graubner: This may be the case for the numerical computation (without principle values), but elliptic integrals are well studied for centuries and there should be a definite value.

Comment: for $\pi/4\leqslant x\leqslant \pi/2$ we have $1-4\sin^2 x<0$.

Comment: @arian: Yes, and this gives a non-zero imaginary part.

Comment: I don't believe "True value" is a term that makes sense in this context.

Comment: Maple `2018` gives `-I*EllipticK((1/2)*sqrt(3))*(1/2)-I*EllipticPi(3/2, (1/2)*sqrt(3))*(1/2)+(1/2)*EllipticPi(1/2, 1/2)`=`-0.363960575-0.5391289120*I`

Comment: @mariusz-iwaniuk: That's interesting, looks like the newer version agrees with Wolfram. My Maple results come from VR4 and 7. If I enter your expression into Maple 7, the result is again $1.20683575210 - 0.53912891187 i$ with the terms
`EllipticPi}(1/2, 1/2)/2` $\approx 1.2068,$
`I*EllipticPi(3/2, (1/2)*sqrt(3))*(1/2))` $\approx -0.5391289 i$ and
`I*EllipticK((1/2)*sqrt(3))*(1/2))` $\approx  1.07825782 i$. Where are the differences to your version?

Comment: `EllipticPi(1/2, 1/2)/2`$\approx 1.206835752$,`I*EllipticPi(3/2, (1/2)*sqrt(3))*(1/2)`$\approx 1.570796327-0.5391289120*I$,`I*EllipticK((1/2)*sqrt(3))*(1/2)`$\approx 1.078257824*I$

Comment: @mariusz-iwaniuk: Thank you. $1.570796327$ looks like $\pi/2$. Can you get a general transformation for 
`EllipticPi(n,k)` for $n>1, k>1?$ If yes, post it as answer.

Comment: What do you mean general transformation?

Comment: @mariusz-iwaniuk: For example: A formula for `EllipticPi(n,k)` for $n>1, k>1$ with terms of functions with modulus $< 1$. Like the missing Reciprocal Modulus Transformations for the elliptic integral third kind  [here](http://analyticphysics.com/Mathematical%20Methods/A%20Miscellany%20of%20Elliptic%20Integrals.htm). There is a RMT on [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7.E4) for the incomplete integral but a complete integral does not transform into other complete integrals.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the principal value, we can use contour integration.

Using the substitution $z=e^{ix}$, we have
$$\newcommand{\PV}{\operatorname{PV}}
\begin{align}
\PV\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1-2\sin^2(x)\right)\sqrt{1-4\sin^2(x)}}
&=\PV\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\cos(2x)\sqrt{2\cos(2x)-1}}\\
&=\PV\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2\cos(x)\sqrt{2\cos(x)-1}}\\
&=\PV\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2\cos(x)\sqrt{2\cos(x)-1}}\\
&=\frac1{2i}\oint_\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\left(z^2+1\right)\sqrt{z+1/z-1}}\\
&=\frac1{2i}\oint_\gamma\sqrt{\frac{z}{z^2-z+1}}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the counterclockwise circle of radius $1$ with two infinitesimal green semi-circular detours around the singularities and two infinitesimal red semi-circular detours around the branch cuts $X=e^{\pi i/3}[0,1]\cup e^{-\pi i/3}[1,\infty]$ :

[image]

Since the residues at $i$ and $-i$ are negatives, the contributions from the infinitesimal green semi-circles cancel. The integrals along the infinitesimal red semi-circles are bounded by $O\!\left(\sqrt{r}\right)$ as $r\to0$, so those integrals vanish.

$f(z)=\sqrt{\frac{z}{z^2-z+1}}$ is well-defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus X$ if we set $f(1)=1$. On $|z|=1$, $f(z)\gt0$ for $\operatorname{Re}(z)\gt\frac12$ and $i\,f(z)\gt0$ for $\operatorname{Re}(z)\lt\frac12$.

The contour above can be contracted about the finite part of the branch cut, $e^{\pi i/3}[0,1]$:

[image]

On the right side of the branch cut, using the substitution $z=te^{\pi i/3}$ and the formula
$$
\sqrt{a+bi\vphantom{b^2}}=
\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2}+i\operatorname{sgn}(b)\sqrt{\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}2}\tag2
$$
we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(z)
&=f\!\left(te^{\pi i/3}\right)\\[9pt]
&=\sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t^3}\left(\frac{1-t}2+i\sqrt3\frac{1+t}2\right)}\\[3pt]
&=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{t}{1-t^3}}\left(\sqrt{1-t+2\sqrt{1+t+t^2}}+i\sqrt{-1+t+2\sqrt{1+t+t^2}}\right)\\[9pt]
&=g(t)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Notice that $f(z)=g(t)$ is in the first quadrant.

On the left side of the branch cut, $f(z)$ is the negative of that given above. Then $f(z)=-g(t)$ is in the third quadrant.

Furthermore, on the right side of the branch cut
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1}
&=\frac{e^{\pi i/3}\mathrm{d}t}{t^2e^{2\pi i/3}+1}\\
&=\left(\frac{1+t^2}2+i\sqrt3\frac{1-t^2}2\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1-t^2+t^4}\\[6pt]
&=h(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag4
\end{align}
$$
on the left side of the branch cut, the direction is reversed, so the sign of $h(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$ is negated.

Thus, the integral on both sides of the branch cut is twice the integral on the right side. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{2i}\oint_\gamma\sqrt{\frac{z}{z^2-z+1}}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1}
&=2\cdot\frac1{2i}\int_0^1g(t)\,h(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=-i\int_0^1g(t)\,h(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Using $(3)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$, we can compute the integral numerically:
$$
1.2068357521005973203335-0.5391289118749108088597i\tag6
$$

Comment: Just curious, what kind of graphing software did you use?

Comment: @SangchulLee: [Intaglio](http://purgatorydesign.com/Intaglio/), which I believe is Mac-only.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the information!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get a correct numerical estimate if you don't specify that you're computing the principal value.

Using the parameter notation,
$$\operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_0^{\pi/2}
\frac {dx} {(1 - n \sin^2 x) \sqrt {1 - m \sin^2 x}} = \\
\frac 1 {\sqrt m} \operatorname\Pi \left( \frac n m, \frac 1 m \right) +
 \frac i {(n - 1) \sqrt m} \left(
  \operatorname K \left( \frac {m - 1} m \right) -
   \operatorname\Pi \left( \frac {n - 1} n, \frac {m - 1} m \right) \right), \\
m > n > 1.$$
There is no ambiguity because the principal value is well-defined and the elliptic integrals on the rhs do not depend on the analytic continuation choice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Meanwhile I found another solution (see edit), but I will test your suggestion.

Comment: Can you give a reference? Is there a typo? Because for $n=2, m=4$ your formula gives
$$\frac{1}{2}\Pi \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}\right) +
  \frac{i}{2} \left(K \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) -
  \Pi \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{3}\right) \right) $$
which Mathematica evaluates to 
$1.20683575210060-0.539128911874911 \;i$ and this is the (wrong?) Maple 7 result from my question.

Comment: I used the [Carlson symmetric form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson_symmetric_form). $\Pi$ is converted to $R_F$ and $R_J$, then the formula for the principal value case is used, which in fact holds not only for positive $x, y, z$, then the result can be converted back to $\Pi$ with arguments in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: $1.2 − .54 i$ is the correct value, which can be easily verified by numerical integration. Just calculate the integral over $[a, b - \epsilon] \cup [b + \epsilon, c]$ if your CAS cannot do principal value integrals numerically. And make sure you're not using symbolic integration, where it's possible that you're getting a wrong symbolic result and then evaluating it numerically.

Comment: Just two notes. First: I used the real form of the Carlson integrals in my routines and got consistent results for $k<1$. Note that your Wiki reference excludes $k=2$ because $k^2 \sin^2 (\pi/2) > 1.$  Second: MPMath, which definitely (it comes with source code) uses the (complex) Carlson form, gives for $n=2, m=4$  the result `ellippi(2,4) = mpc(real='-0.36396057469437', imag='-0.5391289118752')`

Comment: The statement is this: the p.v. integral in my answer is equal to $R_F(0, 1 - m, 1) + (n/3) R_J(0, 1 - m, 1, 1 - n)$ when $m > n > 1$, with $R_J$ also understood in the sense of the p.v. When you write $\Pi(2, 4)$, first you have to say how you define it. For a fixed $n$, $m = 1$ is a branch point in the $m$ plane. When you continue the function from $(0, 1)$ and place the branch cut on $[1, \infty)$ (which is the natural choice but not unique), you still need to define its value on the branch cut. It can be defined as the value at $m + i0$ or at $m - i0$ or even as the midvalue of the two.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should not expect the analytic continuation to coincide with the p.v. integral. If you're saying that $\operatorname{ellippi}(n, m)$ is defined by the principal value integral in my answer (let's call it $I(n, m)$), then $\operatorname{ellippi}$ is not correct.

Comment: The whole point of my question is, that I do not how all the different CAS functions are exactly defined, or what the exact relation of the integral to the CAS supplied functions are, compared to the standard range $n<1, 0 \le k < 1$ (see
[Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=EllipticPi), 
[Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticPi.html),
[MPMath](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/elliptic.html#ellippi)). So you are saying, that their results are wrong? Or that I cannot compute the integral with these functions?

Comment: I also don't know how $\Pi$ is defined in a CAS. It's likely defined by analytic continuation (in MPMath as well), but an analytic continuation is not unique, you have a potentially multi-valued function because of the square root. Plus you also need to extend the definition to $n > 1$. While in the formula for $I(n, m)$ both the lhs and the rhs are uniquely defined.

Comment: Many thanks again. Your comments were very helpful and give a lot of material for further studies.

Answer (score 1):

To see why a p.v. integral doesn't coincide with an analytic continuation, consider $f(z) = \int_1^z dt/t, \;z \notin (-\infty, 0]$. For $z<0$, we'll have
$$f(z+i0) = \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \left(
  \int_1^\epsilon +
  \int_{C_\epsilon^+} +
  \int_{-\epsilon}^z +
  \int_z^{z+i \epsilon}
 \right) \frac {dt} t = \\
\operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_1^z \frac {dt} t +
 i \pi \operatorname{Res}_{t=0} \frac 1 t =
\operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_1^z \frac {dt} t + i \pi, \\
f(z-i0) = \operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_1^z \frac {dt} t - i \pi,$$
where $C_\epsilon^+$ denotes a half-circle with the radius $\epsilon$ in the upper half-plane around the origin. Whether we define $f(z)$ to be continuous from above or from below on the negative real axis, the continuation will not coincide with the p.v. integral.

Similar reasoning can be applied to a limit wrt a parameter. For the integral in question, we have
$$i \pi \frac 1 {\sqrt {1-4\sin^2 \left(\frac \pi 4\right)}}
 \operatorname{Res}_{x=\pi/4} \frac 1 {1-2\sin^2x} =
-\frac \pi 2.$$
If $\Pi(n,m)$ is defined to coincide with the integral when $ n \notin [1, \infty)$ and to be continuous from below on $(1, \infty)$, the integral will be equal to $\Pi(2,4)+\pi/2$.